# Userform background object

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to create an image on which if a specific part is hovered over, the image hides and another becomes visible. I have done this by placing an image block over the first image and used the following code:

```
Private Sub Image1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
Me.Image2.Visible = False
Me.Image3.Visible = True
End Sub
```

This works fine however, I dont want Image1 (the one that is hovered over) to be visible and just want the user to be able to see Image2 initially and just Image3 after the event occurs. To do this, I set Image1 visibility to false but now when I hover over its location nothing happens. For some reason this only works when the image is visible. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you make the image in image1 transparent? That way even though the image is set to visible it won't be. I don't know if excel will support this, it's just a thought.

Comment: I also had this thought yesterday and it worked :) Thanks for helping. Please could you answer the question so I can give you best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make image 1 transparent. This way the image could be 'visible' but you wouldn't be able to see it. I would have all the functionality you would need it to as well.